# progressView анимация

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar

Как можно сделать такую анимацию используя стандартный `progressView`?

http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=20160721021vmdN1PRvXsWIRfFSCTxE6&file=output_MECfoY.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `UIProgressView` есть два свойства:

`trackImage` - изображение для незаполненной области

`progressImage` - изображение для заполненной области

В вашем случае одна и та же картинка, в одном случае чуть темнее/светлее

Answer (score -2):

Про стандартный progressView не скажу, но такое легко делается на двух вьюшках - фоновая с картинкой, верхняя черная с альфой около 0.25. В зависимости от прогресса меняешь ширину верхней view.